# homepage magento delete cms code need magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, home

Hello i have **deleted my cms homepage code**, now my **homepage is not showing up anymore**.

please help me, i need a new homepage code for my magento homepage.

I have try to fine it back and i can't fine it back. I use `Magento 1.9`.

Comment: from where you delete code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new CMS page in which you put the content of your homepage and then select this page as the new homepage under `System - Configuration - Web - Default Pages - CMS Home Page`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using any custom theme than you will find other versions of your home page. Please copy the code and paste it in your content and layout XML area.
If you are using new Magento without any custom theme than there is no any method which will recover your home page code.
Please install new Magento at new place and copy your home page code from there.

Here is the content of home page

```
<div class="slideshow-container">
    <ul class="slideshow">
        <li><a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}accessories/eyewear.html"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slide-1.jpg"}}" alt="An eye for detail - Click to Shop Eye Wear" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}women.html"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slide-2.jpg"}}" alt="Style solutions - covet-worthy styles in travel-friendly fabrics - Click to Shop Woman" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}men.html"><img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/slide-3.jpg"}}" alt="Wing man - hit the runway in stylish separates and casuals - Click to Shop Man" /></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="slideshow-pager">&nbsp;</div>
    <span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span>
</div>

<ul class="promos">
    <li>
        <a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}home-decor.html"> 
            <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/homepage-three-column-promo-01B.png"}}" alt="Physical &amp; Virtual Gift Cards" /> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}vip.html"> 
            <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/homepage-three-column-promo-02.png"}}" alt="Shop Private Sales - Members Only" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}accessories/bags-luggage.html"> 
            <img src="{{media url="wysiwyg/homepage-three-column-promo-03.png"}}" alt="Travel Gear for Every Occasion" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<style type="text/css">
    /* Reset the .std styles */
    .std ul.products-grid li {
        list-style: none;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
    .std ul.products-grid li .product-info {
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
        min-height: 0 !important;
    }
    .widget-new-products h2 {
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_new" display_type="new_products" products_count="5" template="catalog/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```